# railsのeach文 .zip付きでインデックス番号をつけたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

質問です。この　<% @items.zip(@user〜　のコードにindex 番号をつけたいです。

どなたか分かる方いらっしゃいますか？

Syntax error.

```
<% @items.zip(@user_items).with_index do |item, ui, index| %>
  <td class="invert"><%= index %></td>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @items.zip(@user_items).with_index do |item, ui, index| %>
<tr class="rem1">
    <td class="invert"><%= index %></td>
    <td class="invert-image" >
        <%= link_to image_tag(item.img.thumb.url || "sushi1.jpg", class: "img-responsive" ), item %>
    </td>

    <td class="invert">
    　　<div class="quantity"> 
        　<div class="quantity-select">                           
            　<div class="entry value-minus">&nbsp;</div>
            　<div class="entry value" id="score-value"><%= ui.quantity %></div>
            　<div class="entry value-plus active">&nbsp;</div>
        　</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="invert"><%= link_to item.name, item %></td>
    <td class="invert">$ <%= link_to item.price, item %></td>
    <td class="invert">
            <%= link_to image_tag("close_1.png"), item_delete_in_baskets_path(item), method: :post, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, class:"ml-2"%>
    </td>
</tr> 
<% end %>
```

baskets_contrller.rb

```
class BasketsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def show 
    # same as application controller
    
    basket = current_user.prepare_basket
    @user_items = basket.basket_items
    @basket_items = @user_items.select(:item_id)
    @items = Item.where(id: @basket_items)
    @total_price = basket.total_price
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

each_with_index または each.with_index を利用すればいいと思います

```
array1 = ["el1", "el2", "el3"]
array2 = [10, 20, 30]
array1.zip(array2).each_with_index { |(array1_el, array2_el), index|
  p "#{array1_el}, #{array2_el}, #{index}"
  # "el1, 10, 0"
  # "el2, 20, 1"
  # "el3, 30, 2"
}
array1.zip(array2).each.with_index { |(array1_el, array2_el), index|
  p "#{array1_el}, #{array2_el}, #{index}"
  # 同じ
}
```